# Select only duplicate values from the table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to select from a table (user_id, i_id) only those values that match both user_ids.

Table structure:

| user_id | i_id |
| --- | --- |
| 713870562 | 2 |
| 713870562 | 3 |
| 713870562 | 4 |
| 713870562 | 5 |
| 713870562 | 6 |
| 713870562 | 7 |
| 713870562 | 8 |
| 713870562 | 9 |
| 22131245 | 6 |
| 22131245 | 7 |
| 22131245 | 8 |
| 22131245 | 9 |
| 22131245 | 10 |
| 22131245 | 11 |
| 22131245 | 12 |
| 22637245 | 32 |

I tried to do it with SELECT DISTINCT, but it selects all the data

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT interest_relations.user_id,  interest_relations.i_id
FROM interest_relations
WHERE interest_relations.user_id IN (713870562,22131245) GROUP BY user_id, i_id
```

I expect to get only those values that are the same for both users

**UPD.**
There will be a lot of user IDs in the table. I need to filter only certain 2.
For example in the table above 3 id's are presented. I want to filter only `713870562` and `22131245` and receive data like this:

```
i_id
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: "Table structure" should never be expressed in a picture. (Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)).  It will make life easier for anyone that (tries to) answer your post when this info is given in plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**
An alternative with `inner join` and result for only 2 `user_id`-s. First take only data that is related to these two user ids and then use it as a CTE  (pseudo-table).

```sql
with t as (
 select * from interest_relations where user_id in (713870562, 22131245)
)
select i_id 
from t as a inner join t as b using (i_id)
where a.user_id < b.user_id;
```

| i_id |
| --- |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |

Comment: okay, it works for this particular data. But there will be many other ids in the table. Is it possible to use your solution to choose specific two and compare them exactly? I'm a little confused about this sql

Comment: Yes, sure. Add `and i_id in (first_id, second_id)` in the `where` clause.

Comment: It doesn't work :(. Empty query in return. I have updated the table with approximate information, may be this will help

Comment: Oh, I was thinking about i_id-s, not user_id-s. I will append/fix the answer.

Comment: maybe I explained it wrong. I need to select i_id, but so that they are the same for two user_ids. Sorry for inconvenience

Comment: Fine, I see. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Select all `user_id` which have a count greater than 1:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM interest_relations
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id
                  FROM interest_relations
                  GROUP BY user_id
                  HAVING count(*)>1)
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/D5z2Ii8E)

EDIT: After reading the answer from @stevanof-sm, I think I have mis-read the question. A simple query like next one may be all you need:

```sql
SELECT i_id, max(user_id) as "max", min(user_id) as "min"
FROM interest_relations
WHERE user_id in (22131245,715870562)
GROUP BY i_id;
```

output:

| i_id | max | min |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | 715870562 | 22131245 |
| 41 | 22131245 | 22131245 |
| 46 | 22131245 | 22131245 |
| 47 | 22131245 | 22131245 |
| 43 | 22131245 | 22131245 |
| 45 | 22131245 | 22131245 |
| 44 | 715870562 | 22131245 |